# PNG images refuse to resize?

Tags: html, css

Completely stuck on this one... I've tried various arraignments of max-width and max-height, as well as auto values.

No idea what is holding me up. Here's the effected code:

```
<div class="copybar">
    <ul>
        <li id="copy-credit"><h3>Copyright 2016: </h3><a id="credit-animate" href="https://google.com">Zach Curtis</a></li>
        <li id="social-icon"><a href="https://facebook.com"><img class="icon-img" src="images/iconfb.png"></a></li>
        <li id="social-icon"><a href="https://instagram.com"><img class="icon-img" src="images/iconinsta.png"></imgc></a></li>
        <li id="social-icon"><a href="https://twitter.com"><img class="icon-img" src="images/icontwit.png"></a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.copybar {
background-color: darkslategray;
display: inline-block;


}

.copybar ul {
list-style: none;
margin-left:10%;
margin-right:10%;
}

#copy-credit {
display: block;
float: right;

}

#social-icon{
display: block;
float: left;
max-width: 25%;
height:auto;
}

.icon-image{
max-width:25%;
height: auto;
}
```

Comment: "icon-img" vs "icon-image"?

Comment: @Marvin Why not post this as the answer?

Comment: It's crazy how the simplest things can keep you stumped for hours. Thanks man.

Comment: @TylerRoper I actually thought it would be too minor to justify an answer. But won't refuse to write one if asked.

Comment: @Marvin I hear you. I was genuinely curious as I'm somewhat new!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your class is declared as `icon-image` in your CSS but referenced as `icon-img` in your HTML.

Answer (score 1):

```
  <li id="social-icon"><a href="https://twitter.com"><img class="icon-img" src="images/icontwit.png"></a></li>
```

Has the Class name .icon-img and you are trying to edit the classname .icon-image

```
.icon-image{
max-width:25%;
height: auto;
}
```

Change to:

```
.icon-img{
max-width:25%;
height: auto;
}
```